# GCD Semaphore does not wait (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm pretty much new to GCD. I have this function for forward geocoding and the issue is it returns before the completion closure completes. So every time it just returns *nil*. I found out I can use semaphores so the return waits for the completion closure to complete, but there are very little examples online and I found none of a function that returns. I tried to implement it, but function still returns *nil* even though the location is printed out to the console moments later. If someone could tell me where I am making a mistake I would be very grateful.

```
func forwardGeocoding(address: String) -> CLLocation? {
    var userLocation: CLLocation?
    var returnvalue: CLLocation?
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Geocoding error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        if placemarks?.count > 0 {
            let placemark = placemarks?.first
            let location = placemark?.location
            let coordinate = location?.coordinate
            print("Settings location: \(coordinate!.latitude), \(coordinate!.longitude)")
            if let unwrappedCoordinate = coordinate {
                let CLReadyLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: unwrappedCoordinate.latitude, longitude: unwrappedCoordinate.longitude)
                userLocation = CLReadyLocation
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
            }
        }
    })

    let wait = dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

    if wait != 0 {
        returnvalue = userLocation
    }
    return returnvalue
}
```

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way.  You should pass a closure to `forwardGeocoding` and invoke this from the completion handler rather than trying to return a value.  Your current approach may well block the main queue, particularly as you don't signal the semaphore in all cases in the completion handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paulw11 already mentioned, a semaphore in this case is very bad programming habit. If you are new to GCD learn to understand the asynchronous pattern for returning received data in a completion block. It's even simpler to handle in Swift than in Objective-C.

This is an example using a completion block:

```
func forwardGeocoding(address: String, completion: (CLLocation?, NSError?) -> Void) {

  CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
    if error != nil {

      completion(nil, error!)
    } else {
      if let placemarks = placemarks where !placemarks.isEmpty {
        let placemark = placemarks.first!
        if let unwrappedLocation = placemark.location {
          let coordinate = unwrappedLocation.coordinate
          print("Settings location: \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
          let CLReadyLocation = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
          completion(CLReadyLocation, nil)
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

and call it with

```
forwardGeocoding("foo") { (location, error) in
  if error != nil {
    print("Geocoding error: \(error!)")
  } else {
    // do something with the location
  }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the advice, I definitely need to study completion blocks further. Big thanks again.

Comment: If you don't mind could you please explain to me what exactly does the "if let placemarks = placemarks where !placemarks.isEmpty" line do? It makes me kinda confused and I'd love to know :)

Comment: No problem, `if let placemarks = placemarks` unwraps the optional if it's not `nil` and the `where` clause checks if the array is empty. The `if` condition is true if `placemarks` is not `nil` and not `empty`. `isEmpty` is a synonym for `.count == 0`

Answer (score 1):

the result of dispatch_semaphore_wait is 0 on success and non zero on timeout occurred. So you should change your code to:
`let wait = dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)`

```
if wait == 0 { //your work is done, without time out.
    returnvalue = userLocation //update location
}
return returnvalue //otherwise return nil according to your code above. this code will never execute. In this case, there is no time out cause it wait forever.
```

Another point, you must call `dispatch_semaphore_signal` before your block `geocodeAddressString` end the execution. Otherwise, your application will wait forever in case of getting error.

```
CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Geocoding error: \(error)")
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore) //add to here
            return
        }
        if placemarks?.count > 0 {
            let placemark = placemarks?.first
            let location = placemark?.location
            let coordinate = location?.coordinate
            print("Settings location: \(coordinate!.latitude), \(coordinate!.longitude)")
            if let unwrappedCoordinate = coordinate {
                let CLReadyLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: unwrappedCoordinate.latitude, longitude: unwrappedCoordinate.longitude)
                userLocation = CLReadyLocation
            }
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore) //and here
    })
```

Finally, when using semaphore that wait forever, you have to make sure that the block of code inside semaphore will end the execution.